# Are programs like Symless Synergy and ShareMouse secure?

Tags: security, encryption, synergy, kvm-switch

I have a real need for this type of program, but I am wondering if it is secure when sending commands between the 2 systems? Symless Synergy charges $10 extra ($39 for Pro, instead of $29 for standard) for their program to use SSL encryption to encrypt the data sent between the computers. Without the Pro version, how at risk would this be? Is it just sending keystrokes and mouse movements in clear text that can be sniffed?

I wasn't able to find solid answers for this and have no heard back from the company so I wanted to reach out here. Even though it is not a specific problem with a specific solution, I was hoping for some insight on this before we start using this in the office.

Comment: Please define **secure**, keeping in mind in the strictest sense only a computer that's [off and disconnected from a network](http://www.govtech.com/security/FBI-Agent-Says-No-Computer-is-Safe.html) is actually secure.

Comment: Secure as in how it sends the packets between the 2 systems. Is it sending the keystrokes in clear text and if so, what are the repercussions of this? Is the SSL version necessary?

Comment: Then instead of asking if it's secure please ask something like *does it encrypt keystrokes between computers?* Asking if something "is secure" is so broad as to be ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without auditing the code, it is impossible to say how "secure" they are. However, the fact that Symless Synergy offers SSL encryption is a sign that security was thought of during development.

Are the sending keystrokes in clear text?  Probably. If they werent, there would be need for SSL encryption. If this is for a home network, then there really wouldn't be anyone there to sniff the packets. If there were, you have other problems.

Comment: This was the reasoning I was thinking but wanted to verify it with someone else. Seems super easy to just have it all go through encrypted, but that would remove the ability to charge an extra $10. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 5):

**Symless Synergy** v2 changed policy and requires you to connect to their servers to use their software. I also couldn't find any business address on their Web site.

**Sharemouse** instead doesn't require any internet connection (except for license registration which is a one time procedure) and can encrypt the entire traffic between clients with AES: http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/docs4/09/manual.php#pwd

Comment: Great clarity on this for me! Thumbs up!